# Python3 psutils

Tags: python, cpu-usage, cpu-speed, psutil

does anyone have an idea why psutil's cpu_freq() returns empty? I'm running python 3.4 on Debian linux 8.7.1. I've tried with and without elevated rights and gotten the same result.

```
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.cpu_freq()
[]
>>>
```

Other CPU information (such as cpu_stats() is returned correctly.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does the path `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq` exist on your system? If so, are there `policy*` directories in there with `scaling_*_freq` files?

Comment: On a Debian server of mine, there are no `policy*` directories, so no frequency information is available to psutil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in `psutil`, see [issue #981](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/981) in the psutil project issue tracker.

The location of the CPU frequency information has moved in recent kernels, from `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/platform*` directories, to `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq` directories, and the project has not yet followed suit.

The new [5.2.1 release](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil/5.2.1) includes [the fix for this](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/commit/c16db211624f6c42a62623b924022f46a651927e).

Answer (score 0):

**This was a bug which just fixed in psutil. version: 5.2.1.**

---

Nothing to do with python version or code.

Trying to import cpu_freq from psutil (latest - 5.1.3) on Linux systems
fails. The function does not get defined because there is no
`/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq` on the system (as per this line
 https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/76d1fb61c14d286aa645f154f4a2b7a7bae8a828/psutil/_pslinux.py#L639)

There is, however, `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq`(and for cpu1,
 cpu2..)

**On Ubuntu 16.04 (My machine at least), there is
 `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq` but it is empty. 
therefore cpu_freq()
just returns an empty list, like inyour case.**

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug which I've just fixed in psutil.

Comment: And when will 5.2.2 be released to PyPI?

Comment: Ah, you tagged 5.2.2 *as well*, on the sane revision by the looks of it, which is what threw me: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/releases

Comment: Oh! Didn't notice that, thanks. Not sure what happened. I now removed the release.